# 'splain a postgresql EXPLAIN to me

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-execution-plan

Got this here query:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT persons.id AS id, ppm.first
FROM myschema.persons
INNER JOIN myotherschema.ppm ON persons.key = ppm.pid
WHERE persons.id = 279759;
```

The column `ppm.pid` is a primary key AND in the index:

```
CREATE INDEX ppm_pkey_index
  ON myotherschema.ppm
  USING btree
  (pid);
```

And so here's the EXPLAIN:

```
Hash Join  (cost=8.31..3105.40 rows=306 width=23)
  Hash Cond: (textin(int4out(ppm.pid)) = persons.key)
  ->  Seq Scan on ppm  (cost=0.00..2711.33 rows=61233 width=23)
  ->  Hash  (cost=8.29..8.29 rows=1 width=12)
        ->  Index Scan using pskey on persons  (cost=0.00..8.29 rows=1 width=12)
              Index Cond: (id = 279759)
```

It doesn't seem to be using the `ppm_pkey_index` at all: it still seems to be scanning 61,233 rows. Why is this? Am I misreading it? Corollary: aren't primary keys automatically indexed in postgresql? Is my index then redundant?

Comment: Unless your name is Ricky Riccardo, you should avoid the word "'splain".  (God I'm old.)

Comment: I don't need to 'splain to the likes of you why 'splain is so awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primary keys create **UNIQUE INDEXES** on your key. So your index is redundant indeed.

Did you run `vacuum analyze` on your table **after** creating the index?

```
sql> vacuum analyze myotherschema.ppm;
```

I see another problem now: are `ppm.pid` and `persons.key` of the same field type? You may run into *perfomance* issues due to unnecessary data conversions, and inability to use indexes because you are not indexing on casting functions you need to use on join...

Comment: Ah yeah, persons.key is varchar, pid an integer. Would it make sense to change the query's join to "ON persons.key::integer = ppm.pid" ? I can't change either type, unfortunately.

Comment: That worked! I explicitly casted key::integer and the scan is gone. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome spot!  I never would have thought of the datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change it to:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT persons.id AS id, ppm.first
FROM myschema.persons
INNER JOIN myotherschema.ppm ON persons.id = 279759
AND persons.key = ppm.pid;
```

Comment: Certainly postgres has a query optimizer that's smart enough to know the fastest route no matter how you write it?

Comment: Maybe the query optimizer can't be that smart when the query crosses schemas?

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: optimizer has no problems with tables being in different schemas or tablespaces.

Comment: That's exactly the same query for PostgreSQL, it will flatten both queries to a form without a JOIN using: SELECT persons.id AS id, ppm.first FROM myschema.persons, myotherschema.ppm WHERE persons.id = 279759 AND persons.key = ppm.pid;

Comment: Well thanks for clearing that up, all. I learnt something new :-)